# Multiple controls with the same ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-1.1

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'xxxx' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

I want to bypass this validation. I want to have same id's for multiple elements. I am creating dynamic controls and my css class is applied based on id and class combinations. Everything works when the page loads for the first time, but on page postback I get this error.

Can I do anything to bypass this validation?

Comment: I think OP is looking for something akin to an html class.

Comment: A tip: rename :) Use "FindControl" and want it to guess what the element is asking too much, unless the element has one feature in particular accessible

Comment: @user2463313 Are you really using ASP.NET 1.1?

Comment: Yes using 1.1
Guyz can anyone explain it to me why did it work on page load and failed on postback?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions, you don't have to add tags to the title, the tag system takes care of that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: I am generating controls dynamically and this thing worked for me

objButton.Attributes.Add("id", "duplicateID");
i can have as may as buttons with same id, this way. ASP.net does not bug me. :)

This Works!!!

So, thing is we can have multiple controls with same id's.

Can anybody tell me one thng thoug, why does i work when i add attribut like this and it does not work when i do 

objButton.ID = "duplicateID" ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have several elements with the same Server ID inside a common NamingContainer.

If you really want to have the same Server ID, put your controls inside separate NamingContainer (RepeaterItem?).

Now if you need the same Html/DOM ID, you can't have that.

Use something else than the Id to distinct your elements from a CSS point of view.

You could use partially matching ID though...

```
*[id*="_MyButtonID"].red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Naming container. Are you saying this is allowed ?

<div id = "one"><table id ="duplicate"></table></div>
<div id = "two"><table id ="duplicate"></table></div>

since id of both divs are different, table can have same ID ?

Comment: No, that's not a naming container, a naming container is something ASP.Net handles. In generated html code, you can see naming container effect on your html elements ID (something like "ctrl001..._MyActualServerID")

Comment: I am generating controls dynamically and this thing worked for me

objButton.Attributes.Add("id", "duplicateID");
i can have as may as buttons with same id, this way. ASP.net does not bug me. :)

Comment: I am marking this as an answer, because this one was the closet to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML, you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID. Sounds more logical that you rewrite your CSS to not be based on ID.

Comment: Ok, but I still recommend to rewrite the CSS.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you please tell me why did i get the error on postback only?

Comment: cannot and should not is not the same thing. :-) Most browsers display pages with duplicate id's on elements, so you definitely *can* have two controls with the same id.

Comment: I am generating controls dynamically and this thing worked for me

objButton.Attributes.Add("id", "duplicateID");
i can have as may as buttons with same id, this way. ASP.net does not bug me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, ASP requires unique IDs. Otherwise how will know which control to reference in the code?

E.g

```
string x = NameBox.Text;
```

Well which one would you use if you had 20 of those, all with different content?

I would suggest you rewrite your CSS to not be based on IDs, maybe follow Harry Roberts way of [Hashed Classes](http://csswizardry.com/2013/05/hashed-classes-in-css/)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the funny thing is it worked during page load as i mentioned, but after postback it gave me this error.
I am recreating controls after postback

Comment: I am generating controls dynamically and this thing worked for me

objButton.Attributes.Add("id", "duplicateID");
i can have as may as buttons with same id, this way. ASP.net does not bug me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use you give your controls multiple classes instead of relying on the IDs? Trying to use controls with the same IDs really isn't going to work.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="textFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="name firstname" />
<asp:TextBox id="textLastName" runat="server" CssClass="name lastname" />
```

In your CSS you can then use selectors such as **.name.firstname** to select elements with BOTH the name and firstname class

**Note** - there's no space between the class names **.name.firstname**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will try this one as well.